# Why is it getting Error?

Tags: json, ajax

> Error: Parse error on line 1: function search(sour ^ Expecting
>   'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Code:

```
function search(source) {                                                                 
$.ajax({
    url: "index.ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: { action:"search", source:source, form:$("form#main").serialize() },
    success: function(data) {

        //table
        $('#table_data').html(data.table);
        $("input[name='count']").val(data.count);
        $("#time").html(data.time);

        //pagination
        from = Number($("input[name='start']").val());
        to = (Number(data.count) > (Number($("input[name='limit']").val())+from)) ? Number($("input[name='limit']").val())+from : data.count;
        if(data.count == 0) {
            $('#page_info').html('<p>No results found.</p>');
            $('#next').hide();
        } else {
            $('#page_info').html('<p>Showing '+(from+1)+' to '+to+' of '+data.count+'  records in total.</p>');
            $('#next').show();
        }

    },
    error: function(data) {
        $('#table_data').html('<tr><td colspan="20">Results error. Please contact admin.</td><tr>');
        $("#page_info").html("<p>Load error.</p>");
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify the context in which you're getting this error? Are you trying to parse the code you've quoted as a JSON string?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add explanation of code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: for some strange reason the ajax call was not capable of success however I found the problem there was a issue with a line in my php function on a seperate page.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question isn't clear, it seems as if you may be trying to parse the code you've quoted as a JSON string.

This is invalid, and will result in the error you've quoted in the question title.

JSON strings cannot contain code; they must only contain data. As soon as it contains code it is not JSON and more, but JavaScript.

Without more context, I can't really give any direct advice on how to fix this, but it's I suspect you'll need to change your whole approach to what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
function accounts_table($load, $aid=false, $level) {


    $tmp = explode(":", $level);
    $level = $level ? end($tmp) : false;            


    $sorting_filters = get_call_sorting_filters();  

    $table = "";
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Code-only answers are discouraged, because they are less useful. Please answer *how?* and *why?* your code works, too!

Comment: The problem was that $tmp was not set to = explode instead it was: $level = $level ? end(explode(":", $level)) : false;  but you cannot do this so i created a $tmp var and set it = to the explode.